# Why are my object's assigned variables tuples?

Tags: python, class, object, variables, types

I'm trying to first create an empty object and then assign variables to it with values. However, when I print the object variables, I discover they are of type `tuple`. Why aren't they just of type `str` or `int` for example?

I'm fairly new to Python so I might be missing something obvious to some.

Code that creates the object:

```
def getDbPoolConfig(self):
    settingName = "pool"
    dbConfig = EmptyObject()
    dbConfig.host = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["HOST"],
    dbConfig.port = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["PORT"],
    dbConfig.user = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["USER"],
    dbConfig.password = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["PASSWORD"],
    dbConfig.dbName = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["NAME"]

    return dbConfig
```

Code that uses the object and prints the object variables:

```
def dbConnect(self):
    dbConfig = self.getDbPoolConfig()
    print(dbConfig.host)
    print(dbConfig.port)
    print(type(dbConfig.port))
    dbConnection = psycopg2.connect(user=dbConfig.user, password=dbConfig.password, dbname=dbConfig.dbName, host=dbConfig.host,port=dbConfig.port)
    return dbConnection
```

Class:

```
class EmptyObject():
    pass
```

Printed result:

```
('172.16.18.2',)
('5432',)
<class 'tuple'>
invalid port number: "('5432'"
invalid port number: ")"
```

Comment: `settings.DATABASES[settingName]["HOST"],` is the same as `(settings.DATABASES[settingName]["HOST"], )`, so a tuple containing one object

Comment: Off-topic: Those "variables" are known as "attributes". It also looked like you're indenting with tab characters, which are discouraged (tough legal). Suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't remove the commas when assigning the object variables. Remove the commas like this and it will work as expected:

```
def getDbPoolConfig(self):
        settingName = "pool"
        dbConfig = EmptyObject()
        dbConfig.host = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["HOST"] # Removed commas here
        dbConfig.port = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["PORT"]
        dbConfig.user = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["USER"]
        dbConfig.password = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["PASSWORD"]
        dbConfig.dbName = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["NAME"]

        return dbConfig
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dbConfig.host = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["HOST"],
dbConfig.port = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["PORT"],
dbConfig.user = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["USER"],
dbConfig.password = settings.DATABASES[settingName]["PASSWORD"],
```

Take out those commas at the end.  That's the cause.

Comment: I just realized that. Now it works. Thank you!